# Large data retrieval from IBM Domino

Tags: java, lotus-domino, data-retrieval

I am trying to collect account data and group data from IBM Domino v9.0.

The code that I wrote  for collecting data used the lotus.domino.View API. The code works fine for a small data set, I ran the code for **40 users** and it was fine. When I ran the code to extract the data for **10k users**, it takes roughly around **3-4 hrs** to extract the data, which is not acceptable.

Can you please suggest me some other API with which we can retrieve data at much faster rate?

The code that i am currently using is as follows:

```
private static void testUserDataRetrieval(String host, String userName, String password) throws Exception{
    Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(host, userName, password);
    Database db = s.getDatabase(s.getServerName(), "names");
    File outFile = new File("C:\\Users\\vishva\\Desktop\\dominoExtract.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outFile);
    View view = db.getView("($Users)");
    ViewEntryCollection entryCollection = view.getAllEntries();
    writer.write("\n--------------------------------- Printing data for view:"+view.getName()+"("+view.getEntryCount()+")--------------------------------------------");
    Vector<Object> columnNames = view.getColumnNames();
    for(int i = 0; i< entryCollection.getCount(); i++){
        ViewEntry entry = entryCollection.getNextEntry();
        if(entry == null) continue;
        Vector<Object> colValues = entry.getColumnValues();
        for(int j = 0; j < columnNames.size(); j++)
            writer.write("\n"+columnNames.get(j)+":"+colValues.get(j));
        writer.write("\n*****************************************");
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Please let me know which other API should I use to increase the speed for data retrieval?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: You read the count of the collection in every run of your for- loop. That makes it very slow. The for- loop is not necessary at all. Second: You never recycle the objects. That is MANDATORY when working with domino objects, as otherwise your code will eat up the memory faster than you can think:

```
private static void testUserDataRetrieval(String host, String userName, String password) throws Exception{
  Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(host, userName, password);
  Database db = s.getDatabase(s.getServerName(), "names");
  File outFile = new File("C:\\Users\\vishva\\Desktop\\dominoExtract.txt");
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outFile);
  View view = db.getView("($Users)");
  ViewEntryCollection entryCollection = view.getAllEntries();
  writer.write("\n--------------------------------- Printing data for view:"+view.getName()+"("+view.getEntryCount()+")--------------------------------------------");
  Vector<Object> columnNames = view.getColumnNames();
  ViewEntry entry = entryCollection.getFirstEntry();
  ViewEntry entryNext;
  while(entry != null) {
    Vector<Object> colValues = entry.getColumnValues();
    for(int j = 0; j < columnNames.size(); j++)
        writer.write("\n"+columnNames.get(j)+":"+colValues.get(j));
    writer.write("\n*****************************************");
    entryNext = entryCollection.getNextEntry();
    entry.recycle();
    entry = entryNext ;
  }

writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

By default, your View object has the isAutoUpdate property set to true.  That means it is [synchronizing](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/View.AutoUpdate_) with any changes that are occurring on the back end instead of just giving you a one-time snapshot.  Add this:

```
view.setAutoUpdate(false);
```

Also, you should probably investigate using the ViewNavigator class. See [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Fast_Retrieval_of_View_Data_Using_the_ViewNavigator_Cache) for an article detailing performance improvements in this class as of Domino 8.5.2. It's written by the lead developer for the classes.  Also see this [blog post](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.01.2013085308KLEB9S.htm) for a lot of interesting detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for their input. 
For retrieving the users i tried out the LDAP API later on, and it worked like charm. I was able to retrieve **10k accounts** in **23 seconds**, much acceptable. The code that i used was as follows

```
    private void extractDominoDataViaLdap(){
    String [] args = new String[]{"192.168.21.156","Administrator","password","","C:\\Users\\vishva\\Desktop"};
    String server = args[0];
    String userName = args[1];
    String password = args[2];
    String baseDN = args[3];
    String fileLocation = args[4];
    // Set up environment for creating initial context
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"+server+":389");

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    FileWriter writer = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        //fetching user data
        // Create the search controls
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        // Specify the attributes to return
        String returnedAtts[] = {"FullName","dn","displayname","givenName","sn","location","mail","mailfile","mailserver"};
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
        // Specify the search scope
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchCtls.setCountLimit(0);
        // specify the LDAP search filter
        String searchFilter = "objectClass=inetOrgPerson";

        // Specify the Base for the search
        String searchBase = baseDN;

        // Search for objects using the filter
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(searchBase,searchFilter, searchCtls);

        writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation+"\\users.csv");
        out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        for(String attr : returnedAtts)
            out.write(attr+",");
        out.write("\n");
        int count = 0;
        // Loop through the search results
        while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
            ++count;
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(String attr : returnedAtts)
                sb.append("\""+((attrs.get(attr) != null)?attrs.get(attr).get():"")+"\"").append(",");
            out.write(sb.toString()+"\n");
            out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("# of users returned: "+count);
        out.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```